# Как сравнить две таблицы по данным сразу 3х столбцов?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

У меня есть код, как объединить две таблицы, по одному столбцу. А мне нужно сделать тоже самое, только сравнивать нужно сразу же с данными из 3х столбцов.

Возможно ли это?

То есть, смысл задачи такой - Если `A, Target A, Target_B` в первой таблице совпадают с `A, Target A, Target_B` второй таблицы, добавить в первую таблицу `EXT_ID`.

[image: Первая таблица]

[image: Вторая таблица]

Пример кода для сравнения двух таблиц по одному столбцу:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('C:\Pyton\File for open\HO_Test.xlsx')
datasql = pd.read_excel('C:\Pyton\File for open\SQL_BD.xlsx')
data = data.merge(datasql,how='left',left_on='Cell_ID',right_on='Cell_ID')
with pd.ExcelWriter('C:\Pyton\File for open\HO.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    data.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='LTE>2G', index=0)
```

Ссылка на .xlsx [файлы с таблицами 1 и 2](https://dropmefiles.com.ua/ru/GX7Z).

Comment: сори, сейчас докину xlsx файлы)

Comment: Сори, за глупый вопрос. Сюда можно загрузить xlsx файлы напрямую? не нашёл как это сделать

Comment: Добавил в самый низ вопроса ссылку на файлообменник

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно указать список столбцов по которым вы хотите объединить фреймы:

```
res = data.merge(datasql, on=["A", "Target_A", "Target_B"], how='left')
```

или для приведенных по ссылкам данных:

```
res = data.merge(datasql, how='left')
```

т.к. по умолчанию, [DataFrame.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) делает объединение по всем столбцам, для которых имена совпадают в обоих фреймах.

---

результат:

```
In [24]: res.loc[res["Ext_ID"].notna()]
Out[24]:
        A        B        C        D      E              F      G        H  Target_A  Target_B  Target_C  Target_D  Target_E       Target_F  Target_G  Target_H  Ext_ID
7   187.0  56907.0  56901.0  18860.0  160.0            СРТ  333.0  10762.0     112.0    3681.0       NaN   18860.0      10.0            СРТ      55.0      72.0   368_1
8   187.0  56907.0  56901.0  18860.0  160.0            СРТ  333.0  10762.0     112.0    3682.0       NaN   18860.0      10.0            СРТ      74.0      55.0   368_2
9   187.0  56907.0  56901.0  18860.0  160.0            СРТ  333.0  10762.0     112.0    3683.0       NaN   18860.0      10.0            СРТ      37.0      82.0   368_3
10  187.0  56907.0  56901.0  18860.0  160.0            СРТ  333.0  10762.0     112.0   23681.0       NaN   18860.0      10.0            СРТ      20.0     865.0  2368_1
11  187.0  56907.0  56901.0  18860.0  160.0            СРТ  333.0  10762.0     112.0   23682.0       NaN   18860.0      10.0            СРТ      35.0     867.0  2368_2
12  187.0  56907.0  56901.0  18860.0  160.0            СРТ  333.0  10762.0     112.0   23683.0       NaN   18860.0      10.0            СРТ      66.0     871.0  2368_3
13  187.0  56908.0  56902.0  18860.0  160.0            СРТ  334.0  10762.0     112.0    3681.0       NaN   18860.0      10.0            СРТ      55.0      72.0   368_1
14  187.0  56908.0  56902.0  18860.0  160.0            СРТ  334.0  10762.0     112.0    3682.0       NaN   18860.0      10.0            СРТ      74.0      55.0   368_2
15  187.0  56908.0  56902.0  18860.0  160.0            СРТ  334.0  10762.0     112.0    3683.0       NaN   18860.0      10.0            СРТ      37.0      82.0   368_3
16  187.0  56908.0  56902.0  18860.0  160.0            СРТ  334.0  10762.0     112.0   23681.0       NaN   18860.0      10.0            СРТ      20.0     865.0  2368_1
17  187.0  56908.0  56902.0  18860.0  160.0            СРТ  334.0  10762.0     112.0   23682.0       NaN   18860.0      10.0            СРТ      35.0     867.0  2368_2
18  187.0  56908.0  56902.0  18860.0  160.0            СРТ  334.0  10762.0     112.0   23683.0       NaN   18860.0      10.0            СРТ      66.0     871.0  2368_3
19  187.0  56909.0  56903.0  18860.0  160.0            СРТ  335.0  10762.0     112.0    3681.0       NaN   18860.0      10.0            СРТ      55.0      72.0   368_1
20  187.0  56909.0  56903.0  18860.0  160.0            СРТ  335.0  10762.0     112.0    3682.0       NaN   18860.0      10.0            СРТ      74.0      55.0   368_2
21  187.0  56909.0  56903.0  18860.0  160.0            СРТ  335.0  10762.0     112.0    3683.0       NaN   18860.0      10.0            СРТ      37.0      82.0   368_3
22  187.0  56909.0  56903.0  18860.0  160.0            СРТ  335.0  10762.0     112.0   23681.0       NaN   18860.0      10.0            СРТ      20.0     865.0  2368_1
23  187.0  56909.0  56903.0  18860.0  160.0            СРТ  335.0  10762.0     112.0   23682.0       NaN   18860.0      10.0            СРТ      35.0     867.0  2368_2
24  187.0  56909.0  56903.0  18860.0  160.0  KIE_CHN_BBR_U  335.0  10762.0     112.0   23683.0       NaN   18860.0      10.0  KIE_CHN_BBR_D      66.0     871.0  2368_3
25  187.0  50041.0  50041.0  18860.0  160.0  KIE_CHN_BB2_U  284.0  10712.0     112.0    3681.0       NaN   18860.0      10.0  KIE_CHN_BBR_G      55.0      72.0   368_1
```

Comment: По идее список столбцов должен работать, но в доке так написано, что я засомневался )

Answer (score 2):

Создайте в обоих датафреймах столбец с `Cell_ID` по которому будете делать объединение. Приблизительно так:

```
df1['Cell_ID'] = df1['A'] + '_' + df1['Target A'] + '_' + df1['Target_B']
df2['Cell_ID'] = df2['A'] + '_' + df2['Target A'] + '_' + df2['Target_B']
```

Дальше делаете `merge` по `Cell_ID` также как у вас в примере.

Наверняка есть способ ещё проще, но такой вроде должен работать наверняка.